# Piping a file into stdin with throttle

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin, throttling

Suppose I have an executable, `batch_processor`, that reads lines of data from stdin and performs a complex task for each line of input. If my data was in a file called `data.txt`, I could run this job by typing:

```
bacth_processor < data.txt
```

or:

```
cat data.txt | batch_processor
```

In each case, `batch_processor` consumes the source data as fast as it is able.

Now, suppose I want to intentionally throttle this process. If my file has 100,000 lines, and I want the job to take 24 hours to reduce the impact on the system (that works out to a little over one line per second), is there something I could insert into the pipeline to artificially add delay between each line?

Comment: Is your goal to "reduce the impact on the system", or to make the job take 24 hours? The first could be achieved by simply running it at a low priority, which means that it will run as fast as it can as long as nothing with higher priority wants to run, but it may still take considerably less than 24 hours if the system is mostly idle. The second can be approximated by inserting delays between each line, but if the time requirements for each line vary significantly, you can only approximate the outcome...

Comment: @twalberg I'd say more "make the job take 24 hours." Imagine `batch_processor` making a bunch of requests to the Twitter API. You wouldn't want to hit it more than x times per y minutes, or you'd get jailed for exceeding their rate limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
cat data.txt | while read x; do echo "$x"; sleep 0.7; done | batch_processor
```

or you could use Python/Ruby/Perl/whatever in there, instead of the bash loop.

Comment: Note that this could quite possibly run into issues with pipe buffering... It'll probably work, but be a bit more "bursty" than expected. However, without writing some custom code, it's probably about the best approximation you can get using standard shell capabilities...

Answer (score 1):

Super user has [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/239894/408348) to use "pv" ([pipe viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)) which lets you limit the rate at which you read the file. It works off the file size rather than number of lines so you will need to do a little math.

```
pv -L 10 data.txt | batch_processor
```

pv will cat the file at a rate of 10 bytes per second. By default pv is used to display a progress bar. This may or may not be wanted and can be turned off with the -q flag.

If you dont want to do the math I guess you could do something like this.

```
stat -c "%s" data.txt | xargs -IB expr B / \( 24 \* 60 \* 60 \) | xargs -IX pv -qL X data.txt | batch_processor
```